# Interface Implementation C#

Tags: c#, interface, constructor, implementation

I should edit class below for implementation of interface but I don't know how to do it. It is not necessary to edit interface? How can I provide that class for implementation? I don't know how to fill constructor and `convertToLower()`

```
public interface DenemeInterface
{
    string convertToLower();
}

public class Deneme : DenemeInterface
{
    public Deneme(string s)
    {
    }

    public string convertToLower()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `I dont know how to fill constructor and converttoLower()`. What do you mean by that? The interface defines a parameterless method which returns a string. The class which implements this interface must have a parameterless method with the same name and the same return type.

Comment: The skeleton for the implementation is provided for you, your assignment is to do the actual implementation. If you want help with the assignment, you need to show it. Also, if you want help with an assignment, you should clearly state so in the question, so that we can help you in a way that you are learning what you need to know.

Comment: What should i return ? I just want to implemant that interface

Comment: @MerveKaya, well, looking at the name of the method, I assume (just an hypothesis) that you need to return a string with all characters in lower. Again, by seeing that Deneme class has a string parameter in its constructor, I would think you need a variable/property to store this value in the constructor, and then call `return myVariable.ToLower()` inside convertToLower(), where `myVariable` is the variable/property where you stored the value provided in the constructor.

Comment: i wrote that string a=s; inside Deneme(string s) constructor but i cant use that variable which is name "a" inside convertToLower(). How can i store the value provided in the constructor

Comment: @MerveKaya Check my answer, you need to declare it outside the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understood what you're trying to do

Try this:

```
public interface DenemeInterface
{
    string convertToLower();
}
public class Deneme : DenemeInterface
{
    string a;
    public Deneme(string s)
    {
        this.a = s;
    }

    public string convertToLower()
    {
        return a.ToLower();
    }
}
```

You asked me in the comments `i wrote that string a=s; inside Deneme(string s) constructor but i cant use that variable which is name "a" inside convertToLower(). How can i store the value provided in the constructor`.

You need to declare it outside the constructor, or it will be available only inside the constructor.

Comment: They worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are already implementing the interface. You are doing that here:

```
public class Deneme : DenemeInterface
```

It basically reads "class Deneme implements DenemeInterface."
Of course the interface itself requires a method called convertToLower() that returns a string. But you already have that. You are good to go. One note is that interfaces are usually preceeded with an 'I' Consider changing it to IDenemeInterface.

-Edit
AHHH. I think Conrad ir right. In that case you will want something like this:

```
public interface IDenemeInterface
{
    string convertToLower();
}

public class Deneme : IDenemeInterface
{
    private string s;

    public Deneme(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public string convertToLower()
    {
        return this.s.ToLower();
    }
}
```